# How to read all IDs of all ways inside a polygon?

Tags: openstreetmap, java

I have an OSM map of a larger region. Inside that region is a city with a boundary specified by a [polygon](http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/1647077/full).

I want to retrieve IDs of all ways (ideally - of all buildings) inside that boundary (inside the red polygon in the screenshot below).

[image: Artyom city]

How can I do it (ideally - in Java) ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downloading all the data, you can use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to do a selective extract based on a bounding box and certain properties (for example, a key-value search for certain properties).

What properties you choose to use is (of course) your choice - I assume you already have something you're using as the definition of a "building" based on the key-value pairs in the API output, since this is a bit qualitative (e.g. is a bus shelter a building?)

If you'd like to install that system locally, see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/versions

Answer (score 2):

I have same need. Till now i have this overpass query

```
way(poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.2 50.75 7.15")[building];
>;
out ids;
```

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1oB